# Poincare return map as area-preserving map

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, non-linear-systems, complex-systems, integrable-systems

I'm trying to get some intuition into how the [Poincare return map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map) is area-preserving (when there are two momenta and two positions).

Suppose $H=H(q_1,q_2,p_1,p_2)$, and let's suppose the system is integrable - say a Toda Hamiltonian with two positions and two momenta.  A collection $X_0$ of initial points on the surface $q_2=0$ with the same energy $E$ will, in general, not lie on the same torus since the second conserved quantity - call it $F_2$ - will in general be different for those points.

Suppose the collection of points defines a 
curve $C$ on the $(q_1,p_1, q_2=0)$ plane (of course $p_2$'s will be different for different points).  We can compute
$$
\oint_C (p_1dq_1+p_2dq_2)=\oint_C p_1dq_1
$$
by taking the contour on the surface of the section at $q_2=0$.

The Poincare return map is constructed from points "puncturing" the $q_2=0$ plane at different times so computing the "equal time" invariant $dp_1\wedge dq_1+dp_2\wedge dq_2$ doesn't seem to be helpful.    Indeed, Kibble and Berkshire (*Classical Mechanics*, 5th Ed., Imperial College Press, sec. 14.2) state that

> It should be noted that the Poincare return map for a Hamiltonian system can be shown to be area-preserving. This property is related to Liouville’s theorem, treated in §12.5, although it is not derivable from it.

Thus, **in what sense is the Poincare return map area-preserving?**

Note: The best I can find is from Michael Tabor, *Chaos and integrability in nonlinear dynamics*, appendix 4.1.  It seems one should consider the collection of "first re-intersection points", which will not occur at the same times, but for which we can still obtain a contour $C'$ on the surface of section and show that 
$$
\oint_C p_1dq_1=\oint_{C'} p^\prime_1dq^\prime_1
$$
with the collection of "first return points" $\{(q^\prime_1,p^\prime_1)\}$ defining $C'$ taken at different reintersection times.  This then raises the question: is the Poincare return map only area preserving for the collection of "equal return points" $\{(q^k_1,p^k_1)\}$?

Answer (score 2):

> in what sense is the Poincare return map area-preserving?

In the usual sense: its dynamics preserves phase-space volumes.

> I'm trying to get some intuition into how the Poincare return map is area-preserving

I'm not very sure I have one myself. But this is a consequence of not only the Hamiltonian flow, [but also its Poincaré map](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hamiltonian_systems#Symplectic_Maps) ([Ref. 2](http://amath.colorado.edu/pub/dynamics/papers/SympMaps.pdf)) being [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry). And, as eloquently explained in Cvitanović's [*Chaos Book*](http://chaosbook.org/version15/chapters/newton.pdf):

> for Hamiltonian flows the sum of $D$ oriented areas $\mathcal{V}_i$ bounded by $D$ loops $\Omega\mathcal{V}_i$, one per each $(q_i,p_i)$ plane, is conserved [...]. 
>   One can show that also the $4, 6, ..., 2D$ phase-space volumes are preserved.
>   [...]
>   The phase space is $2D$-dimensional, but as there are $D$ coordinate combinations
>   conserved by the flow, morally a Hamiltonian flow is $D$-dimensional. Hence for
>   Hamiltonian flows the key notion of dimensionality is $D$, the number of the degrees of freedom (dof), rather than the phase-space dimensionality $d=2D$.

So, all these conserved quantities allow for the dynamics on the Poincaré section to also be conservative.

One can probably gain a feeling for how exactly this happens by going through some proof of it. I didn't find any in a quick search, but [Jason Frank's](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~frank011/) very readable [lecture notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~frank011/Classes/numwisk/) on Numerical Modelling of Dynamical Systems does that in one page ([Ch. 16, p. 101](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~frank011/Classes/numwisk/ch16.pdf)) for the *flow map*.

> is the Poincare return map only area preserving for the collection of "equal return points" $\{(q^k_1,p^k_1)\}$? [at different reintersection times]

Yes. Because that's the only time that exists for the map: After all, if we're talking about the Poincaré map being conservative or not, we are considering it as a dynamical system of its own - and then the only meaningful *time* is the discrete iteration number $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the references.  I'll check this out this week.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a Poincare map $P$ of a smooth dynamical system, given by a vector field $X(x)$ on a manifold $M$, is constructed on a codimesnion 1 embedded transverse cross-section $\Sigma$ to a periodic trajectory $\gamma_0$ (orbit) of the system. Then, the Poincare map $P : \Sigma \to \Sigma$, also called first-return map, is a local diffeomorphism on the cross-section. To construct it:

1. take any point $x$ on the cross-section $\Sigma$, close enough to the special point $x_0 = \gamma_0 \,\cap \, \Sigma$, where the periodic orbit punctures the cross-section;
2. take the unique trajectory $\gamma_x$ of the vector field $X(x)$ that passes trough $x$ and follow it in the direction of $X$ until $\gamma_x$ intersects $\Sigma$ for the first time, after $x$. This intersection point is denoted $P(x)$ and is the image of $x$ under the Poincare map.

The trajectory $\gamma_x$ is considered as unparametrized curve, so the orbits starting from $\Sigma$ return again there at different times, but these times actually depend smoothly on the choice of $x \in \Sigma$, i.e. there is a smooth function $t(x)$ on $\Sigma$ such that $t(x)$ is the time that the point $x$ needs to go along $\gamma_x$ and return to $\Sigma$ as $P(x)$. For some systems, $t(x)$ may happen to be a constant, but in general it is not (especially for most non-linear systems).

Now, if the vector field $X(x)$ is Hamiltonian with function $H(x)$ on a symplectic manifold $M$ with a symplectic two-form $\omega$, then $\Sigma$ is odd dimensional and cannot be a symplectic submanifold of $M$, so the volume form $\Theta = \omega \wedge \omega \wedge ... \wedge \omega$ is not a volume form when restricted to $\Sigma$. However, the restriction of $\omega$ on $\Sigma$, although not a symplecitc form, defines Poisson structure on $\Sigma$, i.e. $\Sigma$ is a Poisson manifold and the intersetions of the level surfaces of the Hamiltonain $H$ with $\Sigma$ define a codimesion one symplectic foliation on $\Sigma$, which is invariant under the poincare map $P$. Now, on each of these symplectic leaves, $P$ is s symplectomorphism and is hence area preserving. So basically, you end up with a Poincare map

$$P : \Sigma \, \cap \, \{H=const\} \to \Sigma \, \cap \, \{H=const\} $$ and on top of that $\Sigma \, \cap \, \{H=const\}$ together with the symplectic form $\omega$ restricted to $\Sigma \, \cap \, \{H=const\}$ is a symplectic submanifold of codimesnion 2 of $M$. As $P$ is symplectic on $\Sigma \, \cap \, \{H=const\}$, it is area preserving.

There is another interpretation, where the situation is more straight-forward.  If you have a periodic time-dependent Hamiltonain function $H(x,t)$ on the symplectic manifold $M$, say $H(x, t+T) = H(x,t)$, you look at the extended vector field $$J\nabla_x H(x,t) + \frac{\partial }{\partial t}$$ defined on $M \times \big( \mathbb{R}\, /\, T\mathbb{Z} \big)$ and then the cross-section is simply $M\times \{0\} \equiv M \times \{T\}$ so the Poincare map is simply 
$$P = \Phi^T\big|_{M\times \{0\} } \, : M\times \{0\} \, \to \, M\times \{T\} $$ where $\Phi^s(x,t)$ is the phase flow of the vector field $J\nabla_x H(x,t) + \frac{\partial }{\partial t}$. Thus, as the flow $\Phi^s(x,t)$ preserves the symplectic form on $M$, the map $P$ is a symplectomorphism, and is therefore volume preserving.

An example is a forced pendulum like this one:
\begin{align}
&\frac{d x}{ dt} = p\\
&\frac{dp}{dt} = - \sin(x) + \cos(t)
\end{align}
with Hamiltonain $H = \frac{1}{2} p^2 - \cos(x) - x\,\cos(t)$. Then the extended vector field  is
\begin{align}
&\frac{d x}{ ds} = p\\
&\frac{dp}{ds} = - \sin(x) + \cos(t)\\
&\frac{dt}{ds} = 1
\end{align}

Comment: I wonder if you'd have references to this.